# Using the Membership provider in EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

1) If i want to use the asp.net membership provider in a code first EF 4.1 project how can i make the relations? For example i have an entity which have a 1 to n relation to the User Table.

I want to write something like this:

> public virtual ICollection Users { get; set; }

How can i realize this without making my own User Entity?

2) Does SQL Compact contain Membership Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using code first, you'll need to create the User Entity.
Then, you can map this entity to the `aspnet_Users` table, assuming you have already [installed the membership database tables into your database](http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/02/installing-asp-net-membership-services-database-in-sql-server-expreess.aspx).

Finally, you need to map the relationships that other entities have with the `User` you just created.